# Controller attributes cannot contain non-scalar\/non-null values

Tags: php, symfony, twig, sonata

I would like to provide my controller object like this with hinclude.js :

```
{{ render_hinclude(controller("AppBundle:Default:Test"), { 'object': my_object }) }}
```

Unfortunately I got this error:

> "An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   (\"Controller attributes cannot contain non-scalar/non-null values
>   (value for key \"my_object\" is not a scalar or null).\")

Can you help me ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: you are using `object` as key instead of `my_object`? or missing the other key?

Comment: "object" is the key, just a string and my_object it's my real object, in this case it's an Entity but I have also tried with an array. Same error, non-scalar :(

Comment: try with `my_object.id` instead of `my_object`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is right, only scalar/null values are allowed to pass for controller attributes when `render_hinclude()` is used, because is needed to generate a valid fragment URI from them.

---

**Why?**

Suppose you try to pass this entity with private properties, when it comes to generate the URI for this parameter happens the following:

```
var_dump(http_build_query(array('object' => $my_object)))

// output: 
// string(0) ""
```

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php#refsect1-function.http-build-query-parameters
>
> If `query_data` is an object, then only public properties will be incorporated into the result.

---

BTW the statement that you provided is not valid, you should pass this attribute to `controller(...)` function, something like this:

```
{{ render_hinclude(controller("AppBundle:Default:test", {'id': my_object.id })) }}
```

Then, your controller should have the scalar value `id` and get the corresponding object. However, use the argument resolver feature to avoid this step:

```
public function testAction(Object $object) {...}
```

Next:

```
{{ render_hinclude(controller("AppBundle:Default:test", {'object': my_object.id })) }}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's works with an object id but still the issue with an array like that : 
{{ render_hinclude(controller("AppBundle:Default:test", {'array': my_array })) }}

Comment: Another problem if my object is Symfony\Component\Form\FormView without id :/ I can't use this trick !

Comment: For `array` values each sub-value must be a scalar too, checks this

Comment: You needs then to pass the `id` or entity `object` to template to do that

Answer (score 0):

depends of the controller routing definition probably you need to pass the id of the object, so try this:

```
{{ render_hinclude(controller("AppBundle:Default:Test"), { 'object': my_object.id }) }}
```

Hope this help

Comment: Another problem, if my object is Symfony\Component\Form\FormView without "id" :/ I can't use this trick !